# XtraForm Title bar text in C#

Tags: c#, devexpress

Please help me to set Form title bar text in middle with text align = middle so that text will start from center. How to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The XtraForm, like a standard Form, use system painting routines to draw a text to make it consistent with other system application forms. But you can override the XtraForm default painting by creating a custom form border painter.
All the code, related to this approach, is demonstrated in the context of the forllowing KB-article: [XtraForm - How to center-align a header caption text](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T103959).

See the [XtraForm - How to center-align a header caption text](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T103979) example for more information.