# How to set XtraForm title text in the middle without making buttons move?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How can I set `XtraForm` title text to middle of title bar? 
I have tried example from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564536/xtraform-title-bar-text-in-c-sharp/25565082#25565082), but it causes window buttons to move few pixels depending on focus.

When I click window title bar window buttons go to one position, when I move mouse over buttons they move to other position few pixels off.

Comment: I have tried the solution from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564536/xtraform-title-bar-text-in-c-sharp/25565082#25565082) you mentioned and all things operates correctly. Have you tried [to report this issue to DevExpress Support Team](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create)?

Comment: Not yet. Do you know if that effect can be caused by some custom skin setting?

Comment: It is hard to say because i can't reproduce the issue you described. Moreover, the custom solution we discussed here, changes only the text position while painting, thus i can't imagine how  it can affect buttons at all.

Comment: I've reviewed the DevExpress solution and come to the decision that, theoretically, their code can affect the buttons. Please, check my new answer and let me know you results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach (based on [XtraForm - How to center-align a header caption text](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T103979) example). It works to me as far as the solution provided by DevExpress team but does not contains `Buttons.CalcButtons` method call that can theoretically affect form's buttons position:

```
public partial class Form1 : XtraForm {
    static Form1() {
        SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
    }
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override FormPainter CreateFormBorderPainter() {
        return new CustomFormPainter(this, LookAndFeel);
    }
}
public class CustomFormPainter : FormPainter {
    public CustomFormPainter(Control owner, DevExpress.Skins.ISkinProvider provider)
        : base(owner, provider) {
    }
    protected override void DrawText(DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.GraphicsCache cache) {
        string text = Text;
        if(text == null || text.Length == 0 || TextBounds.IsEmpty) return;
        using(AppearanceObject appearance = new AppearanceObject(GetDefaultAppearance())) {
            appearance.TextOptions.Trimming = Trimming.EllipsisCharacter;
            appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;
            if(AllowHtmlDraw) {
                DrawHtmlText(cache, appearance);
                return;
            }
            Rectangle r = RectangleHelper.GetCenterBounds(TextBounds, new Size(TextBounds.Width, CalcTextHeight(cache.Graphics, appearance)));
            DrawTextShadow(cache, appearance, r);
            cache.DrawString(text, appearance.Font, appearance.GetForeBrush(cache), r, appearance.GetStringFormat());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed issue with window buttons moving. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear that the issue is resolved! I believe it is good time to contact the DevExpress Team regarding this issue and suggest to review the KB-article.